# JavaScript is not loading for some pages in Chrome, Firefox, etc., but loads correctly in Brave

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, brave

There are a couple of pages that have started to load incorrectly on most browsers on my computer:

https://www.appfrontier.com/documentation/

https://login.live.com/

When these pages load I see blank space and overlapping text, which seems to be the result of JavaScript not running properly on the page.

This happens in Chrome, FireFox, Opera, IE, and Edge. I am using Windows 10.

However, when I load these same pages in Brave browser, they load fine and everything works.

This issue is specific to one computer... On my other computer the pages load fine on all browsers.

I tried to figure out the problem and notice that when chrome requests for some HTML/JavaScript files, an error occurs when evaluating window.navigator.userAgent. For example, the browser should retrieve the following .js file:

```
function isIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  // do stuff depending on the browser
}
```

However, instead, the below code is returned as the response to retrieve the .js file:

```
function isIE() {
  var ua = window.'Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 3.11) AppleWebKit/537.73 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
  // do stuff depending on the browser
}
```

Because of this, an error occurs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

I think something is wrong with my computer but I have no idea what. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling each browser but that does not work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem. It was Iolo System Mechanic. Looking back I feel stupid for using the product because it said that it was actively "cleaning up" windows and internet junk files. I'm guessing it deleted something that broke JavaScript loading for pages that use window.navigator.userAgent.